# Auto-complete in Ubuntu 14.04 terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion

How can I replace <kbd>Tab</kbd> with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for auto-complete in Ubuntu terminal?

Comment: use <Ctrl>+<I> or <Ctrl>+<Esc> or add `bind Control-Space:complete` in your `~/.bashrc` or do @JC0nde's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create or open your ~/.inputrc file and add :

```
C-SPACE: complete
```

Start bash again. Control-space should now be your additional auto-complete key